# Move items between two list boxes shiny

Tags: shiny

Is there an easy way to create something like this in shiny?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the [sortable](https://github.com/rstudio/sortable) package and its Bucket list.

Comment: I think sortable is not a solution here as Functionality reflected in the screenshot can have move multiple items as well...Sortable does not provide multi item moving functionality

Comment: Something like this: https://jakezatecky.github.io/react-dual-listbox/. Maybe someone can convert this to shiny using `reactR` using this idea https://react-r.github.io/reactR/articles/intro_inputs.html

Comment: @TyperWriter that looks great.  Have you had any success with it?

Comment: @jzadra I came across this: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/custom-input-control.html but I don't know if the react-dual-listbox has been converted as a shiny widget.

Comment: @writer_typer Thanks to [pvictor](https://github.com/dreamRs/reactwidgets/commits?author=pvictor), the package [reactwidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/reactwidgets) that integrates with react-dual-listbox is now working!

Answer (score 5):

RStudio is currently working on the `sortable` package: [RStudio/sortable](https://github.com/rstudio/sortable#bucket-list)

Beware that it's currently in development (tagged as experimental), so  major changes are possible and it's only accessble through GitHub

```r
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("rstudio/sortable")

library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 12,
            bucket_list(
                header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
                group_name = "bucket_list_group",
                add_rank_list(
                    text = "Drag from here",
                    labels = c("Ant", "Cat", "Eagle", "Giraffe", "Bear", "Frog","Dog"),
                    input_id = "rank_list_1"
                ),
                add_rank_list(
                    text = "to here",
                    labels = NULL,
                    input_id = "rank_list_2"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input,output) {})
```

This results in:
[image: Example image for sortable bucketlist]

Comment: Moving multiple items in single go is not possible here....Is there a solution for multiple items as well....Something similar to screenshot shared in Question....?