# Move rows between 2 tables in Angular - PrimeNg

Tags: angularjs, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-table

Is there any component in Angular to implement something similar to this - [Moveable multiple Items in R Shiny boxes - something similar to attached screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853627/moveable-multiple-items-in-r-shiny-boxes-something-similar-to-attached-screens)

I'm trying to move content(rows) from left table to right where left one has a list of several items with checkboxes. Upon selecting items from left table, there should be an option to move the selected rows to right table. Any leads?

I've used `<p-table>` - `<p-tableCheckbox>` `[(selection)]` to get single/multiple selected values from left table. But not sure how to bind them to the buttons -

`>`  - Move 1 selected row from left to right
`>>` - Move more than 1 selected rows from left to right
 `<` - Move 1 selected row from right to left
`<<` - Move more than 1 selected rows from right to left

Comment: Have you tried using a picklist from PrimeNG? It might be a suitable solution for your needs.  https://primeng.org/picklist

Comment: @Mouayad_Al thanks for the suggestion! It's not displaying anything on the UI though. No errors strangely. Used this example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-picklist-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproductservice.ts